# SELECT de dos columnas en dos tablas

Tags: mysql

La base de datos se llama `parrotweb` 
la tabla numero uno `usersoperacion` y necesito la columna `nombre`

la tabla numero dos  `orders` y necesito la columna `productName`

estoy primero haciendo las consultas en el workbench pero tarda demasiado y al final no me trae lo que quiero, agrupar estas dos columnas que estan en diferentes tablas, este es el codigo que tengo

```
SELECT 
    op.nombre, 
    prod.productName
FROM usersoperacion op      
    INNER JOIN orders prod 
    ON op.nombre=prod.productName
GROUP BY nombre, productName
 LIMIT 5
```

La estructura se ve asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque no te trae lo que queres? que es lo que queres? que datos hay? que deberia traer? y como nota al margen, no deberias unir dos tablas por dos strings. y menos si no son claves de las tablas...

Comment: Me uno a las preguntas que hace @gbianchi. Hacer notar el error enorme que estas teniendo al hacer la consulta ya que en tu código esta: "op.nombre=prod.userGenero" y no esta relacionando las claves primarias y foraneas, por una cuestión de coherencia el nombre no es igual al genero. pero para estar mas seguros de como hiciste tu DB seria bueno que subas estas dos tablas con sus respectivos atributos.

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el problema está en `ON op.nombre=prod.userGenero`. No soy experto en SQL pero creo que lo correcto es que esa clausula ON debe relacionar un campo INT con un ID que sería una llave primaria.

Comment: si una disculpa, es productName lo deje en otras pruebas que hacia ya lo edite, lo que quiero es que me agrupe el productName y el nombre de operador que esta en usersoperacion

Comment: @gbianchi puse claramente: quiero agrupar estas dos columnas que estan en diferentes tablas,

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado las fotos que coloque son de las tablas que mencionas

Comment: Estas haciendo una consulta a dos tablas y trayendo un campo de cada una, conectandolas por esa clausula del join. Ahora, vuelvo a preguntar, porque tu query es correcto y funciona, que es lo que queres traer, que te trae, cuales son los datos de las tablas, cuales son los datos que para vos deberian venir, y cuales son los datos que vienen.

Comment: y para que usas un group by, solo para traer los registros una sola vez sin duplicados? para eso usar mejor un distinct.

Comment: @gbianchi mira si me trae lo que pido pero cuando lo intengo a mi web tarda demasiado y el server se queda lag, ya tumbe el servidor asi una vez, mas bien pido una forma de optimizar la consulta que quiero que aparezca el nombre del usuario y el nombre del producto que vendio

Comment: Sera que la consutla que usas en tu servidor no tiene un limit? y como esas columnas no son clave, tiene que recorrer todos los registros uno a uno hasta ubicar el que quiere, y despues pegarlos? es imposible saber que esta pasando. Se necesitan saber los datos (solo los que importan a esta consulta) los indices de las tablas, el explain plan. Vuelvo a repetir, la consulta SQL esta perfecta. y para colmo antes dijiste que no hacia lo que queria, y ahora decis que lo hace pero tarda demasiado. Son dos problemas distintos. Esto lo note en varias preguntas tuyas que, por favor mira [ask] otra vez